# Why Groovy file write with UTF-16LE produce BOM char?

Tags: encoding, groovy, utf-16le

Do you have idea why first and secod lines below do not produce BOM to the file and third line does? I thought UTF-16LE is correct encoding name and that encoding does no create BOM automatically to beginning of the file.

```
new File("foo-wo-bom.txt").withPrintWriter("utf-16le") {it << "test"}
new File("foo-bom1.txt").withPrintWriter("UnicodeLittleUnmarked") {it << "test"}
new File("foo-bom.txt").withPrintWriter("UTF-16LE") {it << "test"}
```

Another samples

```
new File("foo-bom.txt").withPrintWriter("UTF-16LE") {it << "test"}
new File("foo-bom.txt").getBytes().each {System.out.format("%02x ", it)}
```

prints

```
ff fe 74 00 65 00 73 00 74 00
```

and with java

```
        PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter("foo.txt","UTF-16LE");
        w.print("test");
        w.close();
        FileInputStream r = new FileInputStream("foo.txt");
        int c;
        while ((c = r.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.format("%02x ",c);
        }
        r.close();
```

prints

```
74 00 65 00 73 00 74 00
```

With Java is does not produce BOM and with Groovy there is BOM.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I would think that the charset would be case-insensitive (it should be in Java), but without any documentation to confirm, I can only assume that `utf-16le` (lowercase) tells `withPrintWriter()` not to emit a BOM, and `UTF-16LE` (uppercase) tells it to emit a BOM. That is the only difference in this example. `UnicodeLittleUnmarked` forces a BOM to be skipped, and `UnicodeLittle` forces a BOM, but maybe `utf-16le`/`UTF16-LE` is more ambiguous in Groovy?

Comment: I tested that also with Java and PrintWriter and none of these encodings does not produce BOM. I think that is correct. If i define to LE or BE. there is no need to set BOM. If I use just UTF-16, Java writes file with Little Endian and there is also BOM 

In groovy seems that utf-16 and UTF-16 produces BOM.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a difference in behavior with `withPrintWriter`.  Try this out in your GroovyConsole

```java
File file = new File("tmp.txt")
try {
    String text = " "
    String charset = "UTF-16LE"

    file.withPrintWriter(charset) { it << text }
    println "withPrintWriter"
    file.getBytes().each { System.out.format("%02x ", it) }

    PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(file, charset)
    w.print(text)
    w.close()
    println "\n\nnew PrintWriter"
    file.getBytes().each { System.out.format("%02x ", it) }
} finally {
    file.delete()
}
```

It outputs

```
withPrintWriter
ff fe 20 00 

new PrintWriter
20 00
```

This is because calling `new PrintWriter` calls the Java constructor, but calling `withPrintWriter` eventually calls `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.writeUTF16BomIfRequired()`, which writes the BOM.

I'm uncertain whether this difference in behavior is intentional.  I was curious about this, so I [asked](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@groovy.incubator.apache.org/msg00245.html) on the [mailing list](http://groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html).  Someone there should know the history behind the design.

Edit: [GROOVY-7465](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7465) was created out of the aforementioned discussion.

Comment: I add some examples more

Comment: Thank you.  Those examples helped clarify your question.  I've edited my answer.